# Binary Tree Search & Tracking

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, huffman-code

I have a binary tree of node containing an integer and a char. I'm working on Huffman Coding and I want to get the binary presentation of the nodes. A '0' is appended to the string for every left branching and a '1' is appended for every right branching.

I'm thinking of searching for a char but keeping track of its branches, if it's not in the left node, remove the last '0' appended to the string and go back up and check the right.
This looks very tasking. Is there another way for me to keep track of the node?

EDIT:
I have to use a Binary Tree.

Comment: Is my question unclear?

Comment: Really strings? You don't want the bits as actual bits?

Comment: Which one would be better/easier?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them - if you're just doing this to personally inspect the results (for example if you're trying to understand how Huffman encoding works) then strings are nice. If you're going to do some actual compression with them, bits are far more useful. (otherwise you'd just end up converting the strings to bits all the time, that's just slow and pointless)

Comment: Oh okay. I'm just using them to understand Huffman encoding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a stack data structure:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29)
- [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

You keep track of where you are in the tree by using the stack in this way:

- path = `std::stack<int>`
- move up to parent == `pop()`
- move to left child == `push(0)`
- move to right child == `push(1)`

Edit:

You may want to actually use a `std::vector<int>` with `push_back` and `pop_back` instead. It still behaves like a stack, but you can get the entire list of 0's and 1's at the end if you use a vector.

Comment: How would I be able to encode the chars then? 0 for left, 1 for right. How can I do that with a stack? EDIT: Oh I see...

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about encoding the Huffman output?

You will want to build a table of output codes and lengths for each possible input character - don't traverse the tree on each input character.

Comment: I have to use a binary tree. See this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:N-ary_to_binary.svg the char N would be 0000

Comment: ..for the first tree. Presuming that there's another node at the top of A.

Comment: Right - you build the binary tree initially but once you have that, you can build a table of output codes and lengths for each character. Those should both be binary data types, not strings.